# ASP.NET MVC 5 OWIN Cookie Expiration

Tags: asp.net, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I am using OWIN middleware in my web app to manage logins/claims and issuing a cookie.  The initial requirement was that the user should automatically be logged out when the browser was closed.  That was easy enough, and accomplished by setting `AuthenticationProperties.IsPersistent = false`.

A new requirement came in that not only should the user be automatically logged out upon browser close, but they should also timeout after one hour of inactivity.  I updated my `ConfigureAuth` method within my `Startup` class to provide an `ExpireTimeSpan` and set `SlidingExpiration = true`.  To make those changes work, I then set `AuthenticationProperties.IsPersistent = true`.

Those changes made the user timeout after an hour, but now, since the cookie is persistent, the user is no longer automatically logged out upon browser close.  Is there anyway to get both of these functionalities?  I want my cake and eat it too!

Code used for reference:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Consent/Index"),
            ReturnUrlParameter = "returnUrl"
        });
    }
}
```

and

```
private void UpdateClaims(User user)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>();

        claims.Add(new Claim(BlahBlahBlah));
        claims.Add(new Claim(MoreBlahBlah));

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);

        Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            IsPersistent = true
        }, identity);
    }
```

Comment: Why would you make the cookie persistent again? Persistent means, that it should remain, even when the browser's session is closed (i.e. the browser window is closed). To use expiry with sliding window, `IsPersistent` can remain `false`. That way, you would get both requirements fulfilled.

Comment: @ChristophHerold My understanding is that `IsPersistent` must be set to `true` in order for the sliding expiration to work.  Is that not the case?  I guess I know what I'm going to try tomorrow morning.

Comment: Did you ever get around to trying it? If it works, I can post this as an answer, and you can then mark it as solved :-)

Comment: @FlipperBizkut is it? according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/mt152265(v%3Dvs.113)) it has nothing to do with Cookie scope (persistent or per session). It should work well with Session scope cookie (hence not persistent).